# Synchronicity in RxJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

I would expect that the following code would run asynchronously:

```
var range = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3000000);

range.subscribe(
  function(x) {},
  function(err) {},
  function() {
    console.log('Completed');
});

console.log('Hello World');
```

But that's not the case. It takes a while to go through the big range of numbers and only when it is completed the execution is resumed, you can try the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sergi/6gpcx/2/).

I am confused as to when to expect RxJS to behave synchronously or asynchronously. Does it depend on the method used? My previous idea was that once we are in Observables/Observer land, everything in it runs asynchronously, similar to how promises work.

Comment: Events and  callbacks are not necessarily asynchronous. In fact, most DOM events are synchronous, except for the load and unload. If you fire a DOM event synthetically, is listeners are called synchronously

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RxJs follows the same rules as Rx.Net.  By default, each observable operator uses the minimum amount of asynchronicity needed to do its work.  In this case, `Range` can run through the numbers synchronously and so it does ([its documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md#rxobservablerangestart-count-scheduler) tells you it will use the `Rx.Scheduler.currentThread` by default.

If you want to introduce more asynchronicity than is needed for an operation, you need to tell it to use a different [Scheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/schedulers/scheduler.md).

To get the behavior you were expecting, you want to use `Rx.Scheduler.timeout`.  This will, in essence, cause it to schedule each iteration via `setTimeout`.  (In actuality it is not this simple, the scheduler will use the fastest method available in the browser to schedule deferred work).

```
var range = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3000000, Rx.Scheduler.timeout);
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gpcx/5/)

Note that iterating through 3 million numbers via `setTimeout` will take **nearly forever**.  So maybe we want to process them in batches of 1,000.  So here we will take advantage of the default behavior of `Range` to run synchronously, then batch the values and use `observeOn` to run the batches via our timeout scheduler:

```
var range = Rx.Observable
    .range(0, 3000000)
    .bufferWithCount(1000)
    .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.timeout) // run each buffer via setTimeout
    .select(function (buffer, i) {
       console.log("processing buffer", i);
       return Rx.Observable.fromArray(buffer);
     })
    .concatAll(); // concat the buffers together
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gpcx/9/) Note that there is a delay at the beginning while `range` cranks through all 3,000,000 values and `bufferWithCount` produces 3,000 arrays.  This sort of stuff is unusual for real production code where your data source is not as trivial as `Observable.range`.

FYI promises are not any different in this respect.  If you call `then` on a promise that is already completed, that `then` function might run synchronously.  All Promises and Observables really do is present an interface by which you can provide callbacks that are guaranteed to run when the condition is met, whether the condition is already met or will be met later.  RxJs then provides many many mechanisms to force something to be run asynchronously if you really want it that way.  And methods to introduce specific timings.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks a lot. I am familiar with the behavior of Promises, but I definitely need to play with Schedulers a bit more.

Comment: A note on promises: JQuery promises run synchronously if the deferred has already been resoled.   Most other promise implementations (e.g. q.js) always run asynchronously.

Comment: Brandon- any A+ compliant Promise MUST run asynchronously. Good answer otherwise..